# White Space on translated strings lost

Tags: translation

This is really crazy – I've done it before but now the whitespaces in placeholders in my translation strings are lost. For example this is translation of my pot:

```
This entry was posted in %1$s and tagged %2$s. Bookmark the <a href=\"%3$s\" rel=\"bookmark\">permalink</a>.
```

I translated it (german) to this

```
Dieser Beitrag wurde gepostet in %1$s und hat die Tags %2$s. Bookmarke den <a href=\"%3$s\" rel=\"bookmark\">permalink</a>.
```

Just a standard translation of the *Underscore* Theme. But all tags and categories are combined without a whitespace. I just get

```
[...]<a href="xyz" title="xyz" rel="xyz">Blog</a>,<a href="xyz" title="xyz" rel="xyz">Blog</a>,<a href="xyz" title="xyz" rel="xyz">Blog</a>[...]
```

And because of that the whole stuff doesn't do any line breaks just a massive line of links ...

Comment: This is not related to translation. Please post the PHP code around the call to that string.

Answer (score 0):

The actual code is

```
        <?php
            /* translators: used between list items, there is a space after the comma */
            $tags_list = get_the_tag_list( '', __( ', ', 'timo' ) );
            if ( $tags_list ) :
        ?>
        <span class="tags-links">
            <?php printf( __( 'Tagged %1$s', 'timo' ), $tags_list ); ?>
        </span>
        <?php endif; // End if $tags_list ?>
```

I've now also found [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/122902/is-there-an-error-in-get-the-tag-list) here – but i think my translation is done bad.

Comment: O.K solved it :-)

I needed to – i don't know why – copy&paste a whitespace in instead of just typing it